# Angular ag-grid no rows overlay is not displayed properly

Tags: angular, ag-grid-angular

I am new to angular ag-grid.

The 'No rows' overlay is not displaying properly in the ag-grid as shown in the attached image.

here is my ag-grid definition. Can anyone help how to display the no rows overlay centre to the grid.

```
  <ag-grid-angular style="width: 100%; height:100%;border:solid 1px red;" #agGrid
                   id="courseGrid"
                   class="ag-theme-balham"
                   [pagination]="true"
                   [enableSorting]="true"
                   [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
                   (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
                   (rowClicked)="onRowClicked($event)">
  </ag-grid-angular>
```

[image]
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into this page: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-width-and-height/

I would set the property `[domLayout]="autoHeight"` and would not work with the style property.